# Stripplot and boxplot outliers do not overlap

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I have been combining boxplots and strippplots with seaborn and I noticed that the boxplot outliers often have larger values that the largest values displayed by the stripplot. How can this be? The boxplot outliers as well as the stripplot are supposed to be real data points right?

This is the code I used to generate the graph:

```
data_long = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['var'])
sns.boxplot(x='value', y='var', data=data_long, hue='variable', orient='h',
                 order=sorted(values), palette='Set3')
sns.stripplot(x='value', y='var', data=data_long, hue='variable', orient='h', dodge=True, palette='Set3',
                  edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, jitter=True)
plt.semilogx(basex=2)
```

Here is the example:
[image]

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Highest regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm making this question nicer, trying to get rid of that -1, I noticed I have `order=(values)` only in the boxplot, this makes the data differ between the box and the stripplot. Adding the `order` parameter also to the stripplot solves the problem.